# php - Firebase push notification with big image

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

How to send push notification with big image, using php for serverside?

```html
$data = array("to" => $token,
              "notification" => array( "title" => $title,
                                       "body" => $message,
                                       "icon" => $image,
                                       "image" => $big_image,
                                       "click_action" => $url));
```

I've tried this and I did not succeed..

One solution?